# Ext.device.Device.scheme is always false on launching Sencha Touch Native iOS app with custom URL scheme

Tags: ios, sencha-touch, native

**Summary**: successfully created a native iOS app in Sencha Touch 2.1 (and 2.2alpha) with a custom URL scheme. In both iOS Simulator and on a real device, launching the app from cold using the custom URL does not pass the URL to the app (`Ext.device.Device.scheme` is always `false`, regardless of whether you start the app using the custom URL or not). If the app is already running in the background, however, then the custom URL used to resume it is successfully passed to the `schemeupdate` event. The launching-from-cold behavior is not consistent with the documentation, and I need a workaround to get the custom URL when the app is started from cold.

**Details**:

Following the instructions at http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.device.Device to specify a Custom Scheme URL for my native iOS app. I am building on OS X Lion with XCode 4.5.1.

This occurs on both Sencha Touch 2.1 and 2.2alpha and on both iOS 5 and iOS 6.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Generate a new app using:

   ```bsh
   $ sencha generate app -path /Library/WebServer/Documents/SchemeTest
   ```
2. Add `'Ext.device.Device'` to the `requires:` property of the application as per the documentation linked above.
3. Add the following code to the launch function in app.js:

   ```js
   alert("Scheme is " + Ext.device.Device.scheme);

   if (Ext.device.Device.scheme) {
       // the application was opened via another application. Do something:
       alert('Applicaton pened via another application: ' + Ext.device.Device.scheme.url);
   }

   // Listen for future changes
   Ext.device.Device.on('schemeupdate', function(device, scheme) {
       // the application was launched, closed, and then launched another from another application
       // this means onReady wont be called again ('cause the application is already running in the 
       // background) - but this event will be fired
       alert('Applicated reopened via another application: ' + scheme.url);
   }, this);
   ```
4. Specify a custom URL scheme by adding the following line to `packager.json`:

   ```js
   "rawConfig": "<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key><array><dict><key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key><array><string>sencha</string></array><key>CFBundleURLName</key><string>com.sencha.example</string></dict></array>"
   ```

   This will cause URLs of the form `sencha:HereIsMyURL` to open your app on an iOS device or the iOS Simulator.
5. Run the app in iOS Simulator with this command:

   ```bsh
   $ sencha package run packager.json
   ```
6. The app will start in the iOS Simulator and will show the URL scheme to be false, since the app has not been started using a custom URL:

   [image: App start without URL scheme]
7. Click OK to close the alert dialog, then press the Home button on the iOS Simulator to move the app to the background. Open Mobile Safari and enter the URL `sencha:HereIsMyURL` and press Enter or click the Go button to resume the app:

   [image: App resume with URL scheme]
8. The app will reopen and you will see the URL has been correctly passed in:

   [image: URL argument passed to resumed app]
9. Tap the Home button on iOS Simulator, then double-tap the Home button and hold the mouse button down on the "My Application" icon until the icons start to shake. Use the red "-" to completely kill "My Application" so that it's no longer running:

   [image: Kill running app]
10. Press the Home button again, then go back into Mobile Safari and re-enter the URL `sencha:HereIsMyURL` and press Enter or click the Go button to start the app.
11. The app will start, but `Ext.device.Device.scheme` is still false and so the URL cannot be retrieved.

    [image: App start from cold with URL scheme]
12. (Optional) Configure your `packager.json` file with a valid `applicationName, applicationId, bundleSeedId, certificateAlias` and `provisionProfile`, and set the `platform` to `iOS`. Then rebuild your native app for your real iOS device using `$ sencha package build packager.json`, copy the app to your device using XCode, and repeat steps 7 through 11 on the real device. The results are the same.

This means that it is only possible to retrieve a custom URL when the app is already running in the background. When starting the app from cold using a custom URL, the app does not correctly detect that a custom URL scheme has been used and so it is not possible to pass information to the app. Does anyone know of a workaround for this?

I have filed a bug report which can be seen at http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?254153-ST-2.1-and-2.2alpha-Ext.device.Device.scheme-is-false-on-launch-from-custom-URL.

Comment: Having the same problem ! Any solutions yet ?

Comment: @SashaZd The bug report I filed at http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?254153-ST-2.1-and-2.2alpha-Ext.device.Device.scheme-is-false-on-launch-from-custom-URL lists this as fixed, but I don't see it yet in the latest beta. We don't appear to have visibility into the Sencha release schedule so at this point I have no idea when we will see that fix on our end.